# Sharp JS Edit DateTimeOriginal, CreateDate, ModifiedDate

Tags: javascript, node.js, sharp, sharpjs

I Don't know that how I can set these properties in sharp js `withMetaData({})`

I try to use it like this but it won't work

```
 .withMetadata({
    orientation: orientation,
    ModifyDate: 'yyyy-MM-DD HH:mm:ss',
    image: {
      ModifyDate: 'yyyy-MM-DD HH:mm:ss',
    },
    exif: {
      IFD0: {
        DateTimeOriginal: 'yyyy-MM-DD HH:mm:ss',
        CreateDate: 'yyyy-MM-DD HH:mm:ss',
        ModifyDate: 'yyyy-MM-DD HH:mm:ss',
      },
      IFD2: {
        DateTimeOriginal: 'yyyy-MM-DD HH:mm:ss',
        CreateDate: 'yyyy-MM-DD HH:mm:ss',
      },
    },
  })
```

Comment: you better read here:
https://sharp.pixelplumbing.com/api-output#withmetadata

Comment: @JafarJabr I did before, i can't find anything

Comment: if you want to make working example here
https://stackblitz.com
I will try to help you!

Comment: [link](https://github.com/lovell/sharp/issues/2760#issuecomment-864447334)